# Why app forced me to use buttons sequently as they appear on MainActivity.java?

Tags: java, android

I'm  new on android developing,
I created a simple app content of 4 buttons and when I tested it on my phone the problem:
button 4 didn't work until I pressed button 3
button 3 didn't work until I pressed button 2
etc..
I want to  make them work separately

Sorry for may bad description

```
package com.example.my;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tex);
        final EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        final EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        final Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String value = et1.getText().toString();
                int n11 = Integer.parseInt(value);

                String value2 = et2.getText().toString();
                int n22 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(n22 + n11));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done    ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        et1.setText("0");
                        et2.setText("0");
                    }
                });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: because u are using nested clicklisteners on buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why app forced me to use buttons sequently as they appear on MainActivity.java?

That's because you did not allow it to have `OnClickListener`s on all the `Button`s from the outset - two of them will only be set if the user (you) clicks *button*, and *button* will only respond to clicks after the user clicked *button3*

You need to set all the `OnClickListener`s on the same "level", not one nested in another's `onClick()`.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //...
        }
});
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //...
        }
});
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //...
        }
});
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //...
        }
});
```

Comment: thnx for your effort i understanding the problem  now cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the clicklistener on button in wrong way, You are nesting them.
You should do the following  -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
            final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
            final Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
            final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tex);
            final EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
            final EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
            final Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
            button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    et1.setText("0");
                    et2.setText("0");
                }
            });

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String value = et1.getText().toString();
                    int n11 = Integer.parseInt(value);

                    String value2 = et2.getText().toString();
                    int n22 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(n22 + n11));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done    ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much ... thats really help

Answer (score 0):

I can see too many problems in the code.
Firstly each setOnClickListener should be independent in itself.
setOnClickListener on button3 getting closed before button.
Secondly you are adding onclickListener inside onCLick which is wrong.

Comment: thnx alot i got it now